# GeoMesa: saving raster data

Tags: geomesa

How can I save in GeoMesa raster data (GeoTIFF, DEM)? Can you please provide code examples? Also, please provide info (links) to the serialization of the raster data in Accumulo

I have only found the following commands line tool:

- http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/accumulo/raster.html#ingest
  http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/accumulo/commandline_tools.html#accumulo-tools-raster
  http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-raster.html

Moreover, can I read that the image should be an image pyramid EPSG:4326 in order to ingest it. What will happen if it is not? Will I not be able to ingest it or the image will not be available in multiple zoom levels?

Answer (score 1):

Since the GeoMesa raster module isn't heavily used, sadly there are few examples around writing data to Accumulo using it.  That said, I believe you are looking for the 'putRaster' method here [1].

I believe the data must be pre-tiled to be ingested.  If it is not pyramided, then only the one zoom level will be ingested.  The benefit of the pyramid is for quicker downsampling; if that's not a concern, then no worries!

1. https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-accumulo/geomesa-accumulo-raster/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/raster/data/AccumuloRasterStore.scala#L193

Comment: By the way, can I also give a time dimension on putRaster? This is not clear from the link you provided. Because according to http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/time.html#wms-time I can query raster data using a time dimension. According to http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-raster.html we can ingest GeoTIFF but how do we specify a time key?

Comment: It seems that Raster which is the input to putRaster() has a time dimension according to https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-accumulo/geomesa-accumulo-raster/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/raster/data/Raster.scala. Is this field used automatically to index the raster?

Comment: In which table are raster data persisted? Any reference?

Comment: Is the blobstore used? http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-blobstore.html

Comment: I don't think the current implementation uses the time dimension as it indexes the raster.

Comment: The documentation for the raster support doesn't specify the table structure.  One would have to read through the code.

Comment: I am not sure how many folks are using the blobstore.  I have fielded questions about it so I know at least one group has tried it out.

Overall, I'd opine that the blobstore is pretty simple and would be trivial to extend to suit custom use cases.